# How does Mage’s Disjunction interact with spells bigger than its area?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

> All magical effects and magic items within the radius of the spell, except for those that you carry or touch, are disjoined. That is, spells and spell-like effects are separated into their individual components (ending the effect as a dispel magic spell does), and each permanent magic item must make a successful Will save or be turned into a normal item. An item in a creature’s possession uses its own Will save bonus or its possessor’s Will save bonus, whichever is higher.

Mage’s Disjunction has a radius of 40ft. What if an area spell could not be contained within that area? Say, a spell with a 50ft radius effect. Is overlapping the area of an ongoing spell effect enough to dispel it, or must the entire spell be engulfed by the 40ft radius?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The spell description states that [Mage’s Disjunction](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magesDisjunction.htm) ends spells and spell-like effects "as a dispel magic spell does".
Since Mage’s Disjunction is an "area spell" it should – in this regard – work just like the area version of [Dispel Magic](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dispelMagic.htm).

> For each ongoing area or effect spell whose point of origin is within
> the area of the dispel magic spell, you can make a dispel check to
> dispel the spell.  For each ongoing spell whose area overlaps that of
> the dispel magic spell, you can make a dispel check to end the effect,
> but only within the overlapping area.

Accordingly, ongoing area spells only end if their point of origin lies within the area of the Mage’s Disjunction spell. Otherwise, the effect only ends in the overlapping area.